# "tty" option detected in CYGWIN environment variable

Tags: cygwin

I recently reinstalled cygwin on my windows 7 machine, and added the cygwin directory to my path so that it works seamlessly with the windows command line.  Every time I execute a command, I get the following above the actual output:

```
"tty" option detected in CYGWIN environment variable.
CYGWIN=tty is no longer supported.  Please remove it from your
CYGWIN environment variable and use a terminal emulator like mintty,
xterm, or rxvt.
```

How can I get rid of this so that I can use cygwin in my command line without the annoying header?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the advice in the warning?

Comment: how do I "remove it from my CYGWIN environment variable"? I would rather not use an emulator, as I like the seamlessness of using the cygwin commands in the windows command line.

Comment: You must have the CYGWIN environment variable set somewhere, e.g. in a script you're using to start your command prompt or in the global Windows environment. You can find the latter in the Control Panel, under System->Advanced->Environment Variables. (At least that's where they are in XP; they might have moved in 7.)

Comment: found it.  It was in the environment variables.  post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue, but there was no setting for the `CYGWIN` environment variable in any script or in the computer properties (Control Panel).

I then discovered that the `sshd` service had a setting for the `CYGWIN` environment variable in the Windows registry under the following key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\sshd\Parameters\Environment`

By removing the `tty` option in the `@CYGWIN` string, the deprecation warning no longer appears when executing commands.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me, and ak2'a answer didn't.  How did you run into that?

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, too! I would have *never* discovered it, I suppose... Thanks!

Comment: My `sshd` section did not have this, but I did find mine in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.  Searching the registry for `tty` gets a lot of false positives; searching for `binmode` is much more effective.

Comment: How did you remove the tty option from @CYGWIN?

Answer (score 3):

You must have the CYGWIN environment variable set somewhere, e.g. in a script you're using to start your command prompt or in the global Windows environment. You can find the latter in the Control Panel, under System->Advanced->Environment Variables. (At least that's where they are in XP; they might have moved in 7.)

Comment: The `CYGWIN` variable for `sshd` is not set there.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for VirtualStaticVoid

You can see the setting here:

```
$ cat /proc/registry/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/services/sshd/Parameters/Environment/CYGWIN
tty ntsec
```

But it is read only.  Here is how to fix it with only ssh access:

Create sshd-env.reg

```
$ cat <<EOF >sshd-env.reg
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\sshd\Parameters\Environment]
"CYGWIN"="ntsec"
EOF
```

Import it into the registry:

```
$ regedit.exe -s sshd-env.reg
```

Verify it took:

```
$ cat /proc/registry/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/services/sshd/Parameters/Environment/CYGWIN
ntsec
```

Somehow restart sshd.

Seems cygrunsrv doesn't have a --restart option.  Shame.  Without crontab installed, which it isn't by default, it might be easiest to reboot the machine.  It is windows, after all.

```
$ shutdown -r -t 0
```

Comment: Great answer, being able to do all of it using the command line